# Inheritance with Object.create in Javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I was trying to execute a sample for understanding the Inheritance.
class B inherits from A.
The example on success execution must show two alerts..

But is not working..
I have taken the example for MDN..

The code is as below

```
function A(a){
    this.varA =a;
}
A.prototype={
    varA:null,
    doSomething:function(){
        alert( "A invoked");
    }
}

function B(a,b){
    A.call(this,arguments);
    this.varB = b;
}

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype,
                            varB : {
                            value: null, 
                            enumerable: true, 
                            configurable: true, 
                            writable: true 
                            },
                          doSomething:{
                          value:function(){ 
                              A.prototype.doSomething.apply(this,arguments);
                              alert("B invoked);
                          },
                          enumerable:true,
                          configurable:true,
                          writable:true                    
                         });


                   var a =new A(1);
                   a.doSomething( );
                   var b = new B(1,2);
                   b.doSomething( );
```

Comment: Your constructor for `B` should use `A.apply` rather than `A.call`.

Comment: @Matt I changed to A.apply..But still doesn,t work...http://jsfiddle.net/visibleinvisibly/LmUXw/30/..has the sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing `"` on this line `alert("B invoked);`

**EDIT**:

I updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/LmUXw/31/

You had a few typos/syntax errors. May I suggest you make use of the developer console (`F12` in chrome, then press the `console` tab) and look at the errors that are logged to it. If you click on the line number link it'll show you it in the console window and you can see which line is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I originally tidied up the code, but I have rolled my change back because in the process of the tidying I fixed one of the errors!

The errors are:

1. `alert("B invoked);` needs a closing `"`
2. In your `Object.create` call, you are missing the `{}` that declare an object literal.

The code should read:

```
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype, {
    varB: {
        value: null,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
        writable: true
    },
    doSomething: {
        value: function () {
            A.prototype.doSomething.apply(this, arguments);
            alert("B invoked");
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
        writable: true
    }
});
```

Note that this code is significantly tidier than your code. Decent indentation and formatting (as well as syntax highlighting) makes a big difference to understanding your code and errors.

Comment: @lonseomeday will follow indentation from next time for posting